# Suggestions for treehouse platform support without posts

Tags: treehouse

I'm building a treehouse in a fully grown 50 foot tree that has four trunks (as it were) each of which is between a half foot to a foot in diameter.  First, is this a good candidate for a small tree house (5x5 platform) that will be attached directly to the tree?  If so, does anyone have any recommendations for supports in a configuration like that.  I have some ideas but I wanted to get the opinions of people who have experience in contracting and even treehouse building.

Comment: Should probably be community wiki.

Answer (score 5):

[The Treehouse Guide](http://www.thetreehouseguide.com/building.htm) is a pretty comprehensive resource. It covers topics from picking out the tree to building code adherence.